# Why turning off condition_fanout_filter speed up query

Tags: mysql, query-performance, configuration, performance-tuning

```bash
bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --optimizer-switch=condition_fanout_filter=off --innodb-flush-method=O_DIRECT &
```

Query (from [TPC-H query-19](https://github.com/catarinaribeir0/queries-tpch-dbgen-mysql/blob/master/19.sql)):

```sql
SELECT Sum(l_extendedprice * ( 1 - l_discount )) AS revenue
FROM   lineitem,
       part
WHERE  ( p_partkey = l_partkey
         AND p_brand = 'Brand#52'
         AND p_container IN ( 'SM CASE', 'SM BOX', 'SM PACK', 'SM PKG' )
         AND l_quantity >= 4
         AND l_quantity <= 4 + 10
         AND p_size BETWEEN 1 AND 5
         AND l_shipmode IN ( 'AIR', 'AIR REG' )
         AND l_shipinstruct = 'DELIVER IN PERSON' )
        OR ( p_partkey = l_partkey
             AND p_brand = 'Brand#11'
             AND p_container IN ( 'MED BAG', 'MED BOX', 'MED PKG', 'MED PACK' )
             AND l_quantity >= 18
             AND l_quantity <= 18 + 10
             AND p_size BETWEEN 1 AND 10
             AND l_shipmode IN ( 'AIR', 'AIR REG' )
             AND l_shipinstruct = 'DELIVER IN PERSON' )
        OR ( p_partkey = l_partkey
             AND p_brand = 'Brand#51'
             AND p_container IN ( 'LG CASE', 'LG BOX', 'LG PACK', 'LG PKG' )
             AND l_quantity >= 29
             AND l_quantity <= 29 + 10
             AND p_size BETWEEN 1 AND 15
             AND l_shipmode IN ( 'AIR', 'AIR REG' )
             AND l_shipinstruct = 'DELIVER IN PERSON' );
```

#### condition_fanout_filter=off

```
RESULT:  1 row in set (13.73 sec)
```

explain:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref                 | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | PART     | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                | 198000 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | LINEITEM | NULL       | ref  | LINEITEM_FK2  | LINEITEM_FK2 | 4       | tpch.PART.P_PARTKEY |     30 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

#### condition_fanout_filter=on

```
RESULT:  1 row in set (30.57 sec)
```

explain:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref                 | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | PART     | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                | 198000 |     1.33 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | LINEITEM | NULL       | ref  | LINEITEM_FK2  | LINEITEM_FK2 | 4       | tpch.PART.P_PARTKEY |     30 |     0.67 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

From column 'filtered', "condition_fanout_filter=on" should be faster.

### Other important things

**this only happens in the `15k RPM SAS 600GB HDD` and with `--innodb-flush-method=O_DIRECT`.

Either using an SSD or not set O_DIRECT, this problem would disappear.**

Answer (score 0):

you have one of the cases where the optimizer searching for a good solution costs much more time than the query it self, but that can change with increasing numbers.

You should read about what [this optimization switch](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/condition-filtering.html) does.

if you need more speed you can try if one of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/switchable-optimizations.html work better. additinal to different indexes

Comment: Thanks fro the reply. If I start the server with `bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --optimizer-switch=condition_fanout_filter=on &` (not use `O_DIRECT`), the query will finished in: `1 row in set (0.22 sec)`. If I start with `bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --optimizer-switch=condition_fanout_filter=off &`, then the result is `1 row in set (3.77 sec)`. So I think the `30.57 sec` may not spent in searching for the good solution.

Comment: you are mixing many things. mysql_safe. disables much more, this make the queries slower as in the normal start uo. so try withpouit mysql_safe dn only compare one optimiter option after anthoer ans see waht works. but please don't mix different things

Comment: Sorry, but did you mean using `mysqld_safe` to start mysql makes the query slower than using sth like `service mysql start`? I have already controlled variates: alter either `condition_fanout_filter` or `--innodb-flush-method` saperately.